# npm install is adding a LOT of stuff to my directory

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I run npm install in the root of my Angular application it ends up looking like this. Its like its installing node or something inside of my app and I can't figure out why

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/31/2019   3:41 PM                e2e
d-----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM                node_modules
d-----        5/31/2019   3:41 PM                src
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM            246 .editorconfig
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            321 acorn
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            198 acorn.cmd
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM           4788 angular.json
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            337 ansi-html
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            214 ansi-html.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            323 atob
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            200 atob.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            349 autoprefixer
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            226 autoprefixer.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 babylon
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 babylon.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            353 blocking-proxy
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            230 blocking-proxy.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 browserslist
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 browserslist.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            407 build-optimizer
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            284 build-optimizer.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            325 cssesc
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            202 cssesc.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            315 errno
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            192 errno.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            343 escodegen
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            220 escodegen.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            345 esgenerate
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            222 esgenerate.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 esparse
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 esparse.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            341 esvalidate
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            218 esvalidate.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            341 handlebars
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            218 handlebars.cmd
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM            428 heijunka-visualization.iml
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            347 image-size
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            224 image-size.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            347 import-local-fixture
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            224 import-local-fixture.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            339 in-install
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            216 in-install.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            339 in-publish
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            216 in-publish.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 istanbul
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 istanbul.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            377 ivy-ngcc
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            254 ivy-ngcc.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 jasmine
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 jasmine.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 js-yaml
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 js-yaml.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            321 jsesc
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            198 jsesc.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            323 json5
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            200 json5.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            325 JSONStream
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            202 JSONStream.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            321 karma
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            198 karma.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            319 lessc
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            196 lessc.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 loose-envify
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 loose-envify.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            349 miller-rabin
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            226 miller-rabin.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            313 mime
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            190 mime.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            325 mkdirp
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            202 mkdirp.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            331 multicast-dns
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            208 multicast-dns.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 ng
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            373 ng-xi18n
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            250 ng-xi18n.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 ng.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            357 ngc
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            234 ngc.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            339 node-gyp
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            216 node-gyp.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            337 node-sass
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            214 node-sass.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            323 nopt
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            200 nopt.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            347 not-in-install
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            224 not-in-install.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            347 not-in-publish
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            224 not-in-publish.cmd
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM         383104 package-lock.json
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM           1572 package.json
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            357 parser
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            234 parser.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            341 protractor
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            218 protractor.cmd
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM           1038 README.md
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 regjsparser
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 regjsparser.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            317 rimraf
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            194 rimraf.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            339 sassgraph
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            216 sassgraph.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            325 semver
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            202 semver.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            317 sha.js
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            194 sha.js.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            323 shjs
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            200 shjs.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            331 sshpk-conv
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            208 sshpk-conv.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            331 sshpk-sign
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            208 sshpk-sign.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 sshpk-verify
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 sshpk-verify.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 strip-indent
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 strip-indent.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            325 stylus
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            202 stylus.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 terser
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 terser.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            323 tree-kill
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            200 tree-kill.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            329 ts-node
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            206 ts-node.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            327 tsc
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            204 tsc.cmd
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM            435 tsconfig.json
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            325 tslint
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            202 tslint.cmd
-a----        3/29/2019  10:08 AM           2824 tslint.json
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            337 tsserver
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            214 tsserver.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 uglifyjs
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 uglifyjs.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            317 uuid
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            194 uuid.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            355 webdriver-manager
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            232 webdriver-manager.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            335 webpack
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            379 webpack-dev-server
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            256 webpack-dev-server.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            212 webpack.cmd
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            321 which
-a----        5/31/2019   3:44 PM            198 which.cmd
```

EDIT
`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.1.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

**Solution**
The solution for me was to completely uninstall node as described here
[ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210218/error-in-ansi-html-10-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-10)

Comment: What is your expectation? What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: @nircraft added `package.json`. My expectation is that it would only install the required dependencies inside of `node_modules`

Comment: It only installs the dependencies, but these dependencies also have dependencies of their own. So it can go pretty far

Comment: @AlexandreSenges, but everything does go inside `node_modules` directory not outside. So if any dependent modules of a specific node_modules will also be installed inside node_modules.

Comment: Are these files written at the root of your app ? If so, have you use the Angular CLI to create your application ?

Comment: @Maryannah yes to both of those

Comment: I might add that other developers are able to check out this project and `npm install` and run it with no issues. I have tried reinstalling node and make sure my versions match theirs but I still get this behavior

Comment: Have you tried verifying the invoked `npm` version? you might be using the same version even if you uninstalled and reinstalled stuff.

Comment: @bracco23 agree with you, but not sure the version might resolve this issue though

Comment: OP, do you have any git hooks in your application ?

Comment: @bracco23 yes, by running running npm --version

Comment: @Maryannah Nope, no git hooks, this is an SVN project.

Comment: Have you tried deleting package-lock.json?

Comment: @AlexandreSenges Fairly sure I have tried this but I will again for good measure

Comment: solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210218/error-in-ansi-html-10-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-10